# Laravel/Eloquent belongsToMany - Property [people] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get people who applied job posts for employer therefore I have manyToMany relation .

Tables..

```
applies   ->  | users_id(employee) | posts_id |
posts     ->  | id                 | user_id(employer)  | (other posts cols ... )
user_info ->  | id                 | (name col  etc... for employee)
```

Post model

```
public function people()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Info::class , 'applies', 'user_id' , 'posts_id');
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $myPosts = Post::where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
    $employees = Post::where('user_id' , $user_id)->people; // this line

    dd($employees);
}
```

It works well if I  `$employees = Post::find(//anyNumber//)->people;` but it have to be dynamic for each employer id .

I tried this `$employees = Post::where('user_id' , $user_id)->people;` but gives error

> Property [people] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Comment: You never executed your query... `Post::where('user_id' , $user_id)->first()->people`

Comment: The question is unclear; presumably a user has many posts. Are you wanting to get the associated `people` relationship for each one? You seem to be going about this backwards since you already have a user instance. E.g `$myPosts = Auth::user()->posts;`

Comment: A user(employer) have many posts and many user(employee) can apply these posts . Point is employer should get which users applied for each its posts.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` returns a single model. `Post::where('user_id' , $user_id)->people` is still an Eloquent Builder instance. You have not finished  the query and gotten a model. Using a method to get a model (`first()`, `find()`, etc.) should fix the problem.
Like this:

`employees = Post::where('user_id' , $user_id)->first()->people;`

Comment: Oh thanks now it executes successfully but i get empty array instead of people infos .. How may I get it properly

Comment: @FatihCan empty array means there's no people associated with the given post

Comment: As I said if I want to see applicants of post which has  id = '2' `$employees = Post::find(2)->people;` gives correct results but query one doesnt :(

Comment: @FatihCan What is your first query now that you changed it?

Comment: `Post::find(2)` is shorthand for `Post::where('id', 2)->first()`; that's different that your `Post::where('user_id', $user_id)->first()`. Notice the difference: **`'id'`** vs **`'user_id'`**. There's a very clear possible reason one of those would return results and one of those would not.

Comment: maybe even a `firstOrFail` just to avoid the possible `null` ... also, technically `find` can return a Collection it depends what you are passing to it, btw

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```php
public function index()
{
    $posts = Auth::user()->posts()->with('people')->get();

    return view("index")->with(["posts" => $posts]);
}
```

This will give you all the authenticated user's posts and eager load the people relationship, so in your Blade template you can loop through each post and have access to the people associated with each post:

```html
<ul>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <li>{{ $post->name }}</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
    @foreach ($post->people as $person)
            <li>{{ $person->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: assuming `posts` is a relationship here, the query is never executed ... missing the call to `get`

Comment: Thanks, fixed up

Comment: I assume posts() means `Post::all()` and it still gives error with() on null ..

Comment: `$myPosts = Post::where('user_id',$user_id)->get('id');
        $employees = Post::find($myPosts)->people ;` I also tried to pass posts id and it makes sense but gives property not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: If `Auth::user()->posts()` returns null then you haven’t set up your relationships properly @fatih-can